# Unable to understand how list is built

Tags: r

Can someone explain me why the code line below :

```
Returns <- eapply(Data,function(s) ROC(Ad(s), type="discrete"))
```

does return :

[image]

*I guess that it's classed by value but quite not sure*

Since `Data` is built as below :

[image]

Why isn't my list structured as excepted :

```
Returns : 
  -> ACA.PA
  -> BNP.PA
  -> UG.PA
```

How would I Fix this in order to keep the same structure ?

**Reproducible Example**

```
stock_list <- c("ACA.PA","BNP.PA","UG.PA")
Data <- new.env(hash = FALSE)
getSymbols(stock_list,
           from = start_date,
           to = end_date,
           src = "yahoo",
           periodicity = "monthly",
           env=Data)
Returns <- lapply(Data,function(s) ROC(Ad(s), type="discrete"))
```

Comment: Can you try on `lapply`  According to `?eapply` `The user can request that all named objects are used (normally names that begin with a dot are not). The output is not sorted and no enclosing environments are searched.`

Comment: Also, `A named (unless USE.NAMES = FALSE) list. Note that the order of the components is arbitrary for hashed environments.`

Comment: @akrun `lapply` return the same thing, how would I sort it or keep my environment structure (`Data`) ?

Comment: I assume `Data` is a `list` and not an `env`?

Comment: @akrun `Data <- new.env()` its an env

Comment: Can you try `Data <- new.env(hash = FALSE)`

Comment: It is not hash sorted.  Can you show a small reproducible example for testing.

Comment: Suppose, you have the original objects in a string, you can use `mget(yourobjs, envir = Data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we need the output in the same order, we can use `mget` with `envir` specified as 'Data'

```
Returns <- lapply(mget(stock_list, envir = Data), 
        function(s) ROC(Ad(s), type="discrete"))

names(Returns)
#[1] "ACA.PA" "BNP.PA" "UG.PA"
```

---

According to `?eapply`

> order of the components is arbitrary for hashed environments.

and in `?new.env`

> env.profile returns a list with the following components: size the number of chains that can be stored in the hash table, nchains the number of non-empty chains in the table (as reported by HASHPRI), and counts an integer vector giving the length of each chain (zero for empty chains). This function is intended to assess the performance of hashed environments. When env is a non-hashed environment, NULL is returned.